# OpenGL glDrawElements transfer to OpenGL es glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

The `glDrawElements` in OpenGL has four parameters.
The third parameter can only be either `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, while the third parameter in OpenGL es can not be `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`.
If the vertex array is very large, the type of indice has to be `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`.
How do I transfer the `glDrawElements` in OpenGL to OpenGL es.

Comment: Note that it _can_ be `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, but it's not a good idea generally. That will cause unaligned memory access (and degraded performance). 16- or 32-bit indices work better when you are not super limited on memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ints as indices for element arrays with the [OES_element_index_uint](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_element_index_uint.txt) extension. Then drawElements can be called with `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 65,535 vertexes (or 65,536 without primitive restart), then you have to break the model into multiple parts.